# robo vsan cluster one node is almost full and the other half

Tags: vmware-vsan

I have a 2 node vsan cluster. One server got an alarm something like vsan disk errors. But everything still works, so i am moving vms off of this storage.

But now I find that the "healthy" server is only half full, while the one with the error is 94% full, after I removed a lot of data.

My understanding is that these 2 servers were supposed to be mirrored. How can I fix this?
Although I pay for Vmware support, due to hardware compatibility I could not upgrade past esxi6.0 and Vmware won't offer support.

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

Evacuate your workload somewhere, re-build the cluster from the scratch and get workload back. Old versions of VMware vSAN had balancing issues sorted out with the updates you can never get due to the inability to upgrade post 6.0 version.

Comment: I've found out that one of the severs thinks it has issues with disks sometimes. I think it removes them from inventory, resulting in reduced capacity. If I clear the error, it uses the disks again and rebalances.
I did evacuate and destroyed the cluster. I will wipe the servers and rebuild and upgrade to 6.5.
Thank you!

Comment: Great! Good luck with that.